# How do I express u and v in terms of the vector space B

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

[image: Image of question]

Hi, I understand what the question is asking me but I am very lost on how to do it. It tells me to express  some vector spaces v and u in terms of the basis of V. Will someone help me do that?

Comment: You copied half sentence from the hint, aiming it as your question, and cited it 2 times *wrongly*.. Btw, maybe introducing $u$ in the hint was superfluous.

Comment: You were no help, you should be more like @Gibbs

Comment: In the future, take the time to enter your question as text instead of pasting a picture. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to people using screen readers, not do they show up in summaries. If you want people to take their time to help you, take some time yourself to post a proper question. Being snarky and insulting also isn’t going to encourage people to help you.

Comment: Your post was also unhelpful. If you don't like the question thren ignore it or vote it down. @amd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually $v$ and $u$ are vectors. Anyway, I would approach this as follows: let us prove there exists a linear transformation $T \colon V \rightarrow W$ such that $T(v_i) = w_i$ for any $i=1,\dots,n$. Take $v \in V$. We want to define $T(v)$ in such a way that $T$ is linear. We can express $v$ as a linear combination of the basis $\{v_i\}_{i=1,\dots,n}$:
$$v=a^1v_1+\dots+a^nv_n, \quad a^i \in \mathbb{F} \text{ for any } i=1,\dots,n.$$
Therefore, imposing linearity
$$T(v) = T(a^1v_1+\dots+a^nv_n) = a^1T(v_1)+\dots+a^nT(v_n)=a^1w_1+\dots+a^nw_n.$$
This gives the action of $T$ on any vector in $V$.

Comment: Awesome! Thankyou so much!